# BrowserUP Proxy Server does not collect all pages

Tags: java, browsermob-proxy, har

I use BrowserUP to create a HAR File from my test and it seems that the pages are not logged propperly.

if i go to google.com and search something and i save the har manually in the browser i get multiple pages in the har. example:

```
    "pages": [
  {
    "startedDateTime": "2019-08-12T15:48:10.881Z",
    "id": "page_2",
    "title": "https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=M4pRXdn4OKvLmwWGtKCgAw&q=Arquillian&oq=Arquillian&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l5j0l5.2235.4511..6303...0.0..0.91.946.11......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i131j0i67j0i131i67j0i10j0i10i3.ny9NQkAY1JA&ved=0ahUKEwiZ3ruY1_3jAhWr5aYKHQYaCDQQ4dUDCAc&uact=5",
    "pageTimings": {
      "onContentLoad": 546.9750000047497,
      "onLoad": 742.976000008639
    }
  },
  {
    "startedDateTime": "2019-08-12T15:48:03.881Z",
    "id": "page_1",
    "title": "https://www.google.com/",
    "pageTimings": {
      "onContentLoad": 605.6039999821223,
      "onLoad": 746.1759999860078
    }
  }
],
```

but if i do the same thing with BrowserUP i get:

```
    "pages" : [ {
  "startedDateTime" : "2019-08-12T06:05:48.826Z",
  "id" : "Page 0",
  "title" : "Page 0",
  "pageTimings" : {
    "onContentLoad" : -1,
    "onLoad" : -1
  }
} ],
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Have you got the answer ?